# How do I determine the target coordinates based on an angle?

Tags: graphing-functions

I know my object is at a set of coordinates for example (150,480), and I need to move it x number of units at a y degree angle. Z

What is the formula to calculate this?

I slacked in math after Algebra II, and I've gotten pretty rusty - most of my programming work done since then requires only the simplest of algebra - so some explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Add $x\cos y$ and $x\sin y$ to the first and second coordinates. And look up "polar coordinates" on wikipedia.

Comment: @Woodface could you elaborate?

Comment: I tried to elaborate in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new coordinates would be:

$$(150 + x \cos y, 480+x\sin y)$$ 
assuming  the angle $y$ is measured from the positive direction of the $x$-axis counterclockwise, as on the picture below.

[image: wikipedia polar angle]

Image from Wikipedia, [Polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).